# cloud ndb namespace per request

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to migrate our code to Cloud NDB.  We have separate namespaces for each of our customers.

How can I safely switch namespace for each request?

I've implemented Flask middleware like the example on the [migration documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/migrating-to-cloud-ndb)

The namespace is a property of the client. So when a request comes in, I determine the email from the accesstoken, and determine which namespace this user belongs to. And then I change the namespace of the client.

I 'm afraid this client.namespace property isn't threadsafe. And i don't want the users to see each others data.

```
client = ndb.Client()


def ndb_wsgi_middleware(wsgi_app):
    def middleware(environ, start_response):
        with client.context():
            return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    return middleware

def switch_user(email):
    client = context_module.get_context().client        
    client.namespace = determine_namespace(email)
```

I could move the creation of the client inside the middleware, but I have read this creates a lot of overhead we want to avoid.
Shouldn't the namespace be a property of the context instead of the client?

Comment: You could consider creating client for specific namespaces on demand, then cache for reuse.  How many possible tenants do you envisage. and could you point to endpoints for a client which defines the namespace ?

Comment: I could keep a couple of clients in a cache. But we have hundreds of tenants. I don't really understand your last question.  Maybe I should create an issue in the github for the ndb library.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in the python-ndb library 
https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/pull/388

The nampespace property have been moved to the context level, so I can change it now per request.
It is fixed in release 1.2.0

Comment: Hi. Just wondering how you implemented this, as the current_user isn’t set at the time the context is created. Therefore, if you do not know the user at this point, then how can you determine the namespace?